# In MySQL are there unidirectional and directional graphs?

Tags: spatial-database, database, mysql, graph, mysql-spatial

I'm new to MySQL and studying about geospatial data. I have read the [documentation](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.7-en.a4.pdf) of MySQL and learned about the `ST_Geometry` type, its subtypes and its functions; but I didn't find anything about graphs (nodes, links or edges and paths)?

So my question is: Does this database have these datatypes?